# Migrating from VBA Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-office, migration, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a series of big excel files that work like a program, but I hate beeing tied up (stuck in VBA for excel 2003), so...

Whats the best way to implement a gui over a excel vba program (office 2003)? (are there any tools for that... I want to move away from the office suite, but still have it in the background)

Or what's the easiest alternative for migrating this code to a more open language.
Any ideias?

Comment: Wow, tough ask. It depends what you're doing. For instance, you could migrate the VBA code to a Visual Basic.NET platform, and then do the UI inside VB as well ... lots of possibilities.

Comment: Are you also trying to avoid the requirement of an Excel license for each user?

Comment: Without trying to move this to a discussion, I really would like to move away from M$, due to licensing costs

Comment: @Randolph Potter: Have you got any experience in migrating VBA to VB... is it much pain??

Comment: I've moved from VBA to .NET and it's a pain. Usually it makes more sense to re-design the application for the new platform, than port it directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can design userforms to act as the UI then use application.hide to hide the Excel interface, so the user never sees Excel. I've done it on a few projects in the past with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention licensing as a reason. [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) might work for you. Probably nothing will just work without some conversion on your part. Depending upon what is being done, you can do a surprising amount in a simple web application, with any number of languages available for free.